# Custom Web App runs even user does not have access to site

Tags: 2013, access-denied

I wrote a custom web app for a site collection. Url is something like

```
http://domain/sites/test/en/_layouts/15/AppName/ActionName.aspx
```

If someone types this url is fine, SharePoint asks for username and password.

But

If a **user, which exists on Active Directory but does not have privileges** to access the site, types the url gets this message **but the code still runs**.

> Sorry, this list hasn't been shared with you

I debugged the code and it actually drops into the **`page_load` even the user has no access to the site.**

Is this normal?

Note: This is a fresh installed machine and all windows, iis, sharepoint e.t.c configurations are default settings

**Edit:**
This site is publishing site. Clients does not have to be on domain to access it. Think two user, user #1 has privileges as site admin to access site and edit, user #2 is regular domain user and has no privileges on site. #1 can access that page and run the code, #2 can also access page gets "Sorry, this list hasn't been shared with you" error but code still runs, as you see debug drops in page_load in the animation gif. Why that code even run for #2?

[image]

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have a similar issue in that I have created a custom page in central admin but when the users tries to access it they get the "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" message my url is
http://sp2016:1111/_layouts/MMDImporterConfig/MMDImportConfig.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the normal behavior on a window machine. This is because of `Internet Option` property is set to auto login for intranet sites.

Try to change the auto login option and you'll be prompted with username and password.

To change auto login:

1. Open control panel and select Internet Option (change the view to small/large icon).
2. Switch to `Security` tab and click on `Local Intranet`.
3. Now click on `Custom Level...` button and scroll to bottom of open dialog.
4. Now, under `User Authentication` -> `Logon`, select `Prompt for user name and password`.

But you have to do this in every client machine within domain if they have auto login.

Comment: Irrelevant. Auto login has nothing to do with this. This is a server issue not a client issue.

Comment: Your problem was, when you access the site out side of domain it ask for credentials while when you access it from domain, it show the access denied issue. Am I correct here? If so, try the above above solution. If not, please correct me.

Comment: This site is public site. Clients does not have to be on domain to access it. Think two user, user #1 has privileges as site admin to access site and edit, user #2 is regular domain user and has no privileges on site. #1 can access that page and run the code, #2 can also access page gets "Sorry, this list hasn't been shared with you" error but code still runs, as you see debug drops in page_load in the animation gif. Why that code even run for #2?

Comment: Ideally, if user dont have permission on web/site collection, he/she cannot access resource under it including Application Page. When the authentication is completed, SP checks for authorization and give this message that, `Sorry, you dont have permission` along with an access request form. Since you created a public site, because of that it is executing the code. Can you confirm what settings you have for web application in terms of `User Policy`, `Anonymous Policy` and `Permission Policy`.

Comment: This is a test site and it's not even public yet, it's not anonymous. It's just a publishing site from publishing portal template. Like I said all settings are default sharepoint settings out of the box. Sharepoint gives error `Sorry, you dont have permission` but still runs the code. So why it still runs the code, if logged in user does not have permission and it clearly displays the error message but still runs it.